# is there way to config show-hide speed in md-sidenav?

Tags: css, angular-material

I use angular material, md-sidenav:

```
<md-sidenav   md-component-id="left" md-whiteframe="4" md-disable-backdrop>
    <md-content  ng-include="'app/components/work/iteration-config/iteration-config.tmpl.html'"></md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

But sidenav moves to fast. is there way to config it's show/hide speed?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the styles where the animation is set. Digging in the code I've found that are these two:

```
md-sidenav.md-closed-add, md-sidenav.md-closed-remove {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in
}
md-sidenav.md-closed-add.md-closed-add-active,
md-sidenav.md-closed-remove.md-closed-remove-active {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1)
}
```

just declare them somewhere after importing the angular.css.min file and change the times (.2s and. 4s) to whatever you want, and thats it!

Comment: I've tried but doesn't work for me. have some working example ?